# Aggregating data in a table up to the date of each row in the table

Tags: sql, presto

If I run the following query, it results in 1.6M rows:

```
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    credit_id,
    date
FROM 
    wallet
WHERE
    credit_title = 'Topups'
    AND credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups'
    AND day >= DATE '2017-11-06'
    AND day <= DATE '2020-04-03'
```

I am now trying to, for each row in the above query, get the count and total amount of all credit transactions for that customer up to the date of the row. I have tried the below query (which is a join with itself), but this results in 1.3M rows. Why are rows being dropped in the join? `credit_id` is a unique identifier in this table.

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    credit_id,
    COALESCE(COUNT(wallet_agg.credit_id), 0) AS topup_count_to_date,
    COALESCE(SUM(wallet_agg.credit_amt_usd), 0) AS topup_amount_to_date
FROM
    wallet
LEFT JOIN
    wallet AS wallet_agg
ON
    wallet.customer_id = wallet_agg.customer_id
    AND wallet_agg.date < wallet.date
WHERE
    wallet.credit_title = 'Topups'
    AND wallet.credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups'
    AND wallet.day >= DATE '2017-11-06'
    AND wallet.day <= DATE '2020-04-03'
    AND wallet_agg.credit_title = 'Topups'
    AND wallet_agg.credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups'
```

[Here is a simple demo of what I am trying](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4asLLA1FRAeXKa8c6NRKii/4), which gets the result I am expecting. How is the logic of my more complex query above different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JOIN` is being turned into an inner join by the `WHERE` conditions.  You need to move the conditions on the second table into the `ON` clause:

```
FROM wallet LEFT JOIN
     wallet AS wallet_agg
     ON wallet.customer_id = wallet_agg.customer_id AND
        wallet_agg.date < wallet.date AND
        wallet_agg.credit_title = 'Topups'
        wallet_agg.credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups'
WHERE wallet.credit_title = 'Topups' AND
      wallet.credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups' AND
      wallet.day >= DATE '2017-11-06' AND
      wallet.day <= DATE '2020-04-03'
```

Of course, aggregation is way over-kill for this problem.  You should just use window functions:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM (SELECT w.customer_id, w.credit_id, w.date,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, credit_title, credit_type ORDER BY date) as topup_count_to_date,
             SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, credit_title, credit_type ORDER BY date) as topup_amount_to_date
      FROM wallet w
      WHERE w.credit_title = 'Topups' AND
            w.credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups' 
    ) w
WHERE w.day >= DATE '2017-11-06' AND
      w.day <= DATE '2020-04-03';
```